# how to do LDAP Authentication in spring cloud data flow server?

Tags: cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow

Currently spring cloud data flow support oAuth Authentication and i want to autheticate my spring cloud dataflow server on cloud foundry using LDAP. is there any way by which i can do it?, is there any documentation available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the SCDF's 1.0.0.RELEASE, only OAUTH backed [authentication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-security) is supported and the LDAP as well as File based authentication is planned for 1.1.0.RELEASE. Please consider adding your use-case(s) and/or any other supplemental details to [#808](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/808).